# Do applicant and dependents have to go together to the consulate (US Embassy)?

Tags: h1-visa, h4-visa, interview

I've got an offer from US employer. I will be going to the US on H1B with my wife and kids since they are dependents.

Are we all getting the visa approval together? They will be getting an H4 visa and I will get an H1B visa. Or do they have to apply separately provided they will join me 1 year after my arrival?

I mean after spending 1 year in the US my wife will bring the kids along with her. Do they have to go to the embassy to get an H4 visa or should they get it with me?